# RA-00904 invalid identifier error even when column name exists

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am running an oracle query in sqldeveloper:

```
merge into invoices c using (select CUSTOMER_ID, INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE_DATE from dual where INVOICE_NUMBER = '123'
and CUSTOMER_ID = '456' and INVOICE_DATE = '19-APR-12') cd
on (c.INVOICE_NUMBER = cd.INVOICE_NUMBER)
  when not matched then
        insert (c.CUSTOMER_ID, c.INVOICE_NUMBER, c.INVOICE_DATE)
        values ('987', '654','179-APR-12')
```

I keep getting a RA-00904 invalid identifier for the RA-00904 INVOICE_DATE column, even though that column exists.  I have verified by running the describe invoices command and then actually copying the column name:

```
describe invoices;
Name             
----------------
CUSTOMER_ID      
INVOICE_NUMBER   
INVOICE_DATE
```

What's going on here?

RESOLUTION

---

Vadim and Justin are correct.  I fixed the problem by replacing dual with the table name:

```
merge into invoices c using (select CUSTOMER_ID, INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE_DATE from invoices where INVOICE_NUMBER = '123'
    and CUSTOMER_ID = '456' and INVOICE_DATE = '19-APR-12') cd
    on (c.INVOICE_NUMBER = cd.INVOICE_NUMBER)
      when not matched then
            insert (c.CUSTOMER_ID, c.INVOICE_NUMBER, c.INVOICE_DATE)
            values ('987', '654','179-APR-12')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `USING` clause, you're doing a `SELECT` of columns `CUSTOMER_ID, INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE_DATE` from table `DUAL`. This table has only one column, `DUMMY`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with the query in your `USING` clause.  `CUSTOMER_ID`, `INVOICE_NUMBER`, and `INVOICE_DATE` are all invalid identifiers because none of them exist in the `DUAL` table.

```
select CUSTOMER_ID, INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE_DATE 
  from dual 
 where INVOICE_NUMBER = '123'
   and CUSTOMER_ID = '456' 
   and INVOICE_DATE = '19-APR-12'
```

Unfortunately, it's not obvious to me how to fix the problem because it's not obvious what you are trying to accomplish.